# Names for civil/marriage partners

Tags: переклад, фемінітиви

> **This question also has an answer here (in Ukrainian):**
>   *[Чи є в українській мові відповідник до англійського слова "spouse"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5203)*

In English there is a gender-neutral word "[spouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouse)" that denotes a partner in a marriage or civil union. Is there any similar word in Ukrainian that could be used by *both* (married) people to refer to their partner?

- "husband"/"wife" -> "чоловік"/"дружина (жінка?)"
- "partner" -> "партнер/ка"
- "spouse" -> ?

Comment: Interestingly, the Ukrainian feminist movement is advocating for using gender-specific forms and avoiding any gender-agnostic words like *spouse*, *партнер*, etc. It may be relevant to ask for their position.

Comment: @bytebuster, thanks for the idea! I'll try to reach someone from the feminist community.

Comment: до речі, здається, у Стефаника або Коцюбинського "дружина" використовується саме як spouse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/podruzhzhja) word "подружжя" has this meaning.  But it is uncommon (in my opinion) to be used this way, it is mostly used in meaning "married couple". I think you will be understood if you say "Його/її подружжя", but it will sound a little poetic (in my opinion). Usually people just use "чоловік"/"жінка (дружина)".

Answer (score 4):

I found this variant: [*полови́на*](http://sum.in.ua/s/polovyna)<sup>4</sup> (literally "half of a couple"). But again it's not that perfect, because while "моя половина" ("mine half") is gender-less, "його/її половина" ("his/her half") reveals gender.

Answer (score 3):

If we are looking for a gender-neutral word in Ukrainian language  - for now it can be "пара", not "подружжя",  because "подружжя" is still used in meaning "married man and woman".

Comment: I recommend adding info that "пара" is used not only for spouse but for girlfriend/boyfriend too. Also consider adding some references and try to imagine that it is a standalone answer - currently this answer is more like comment. (Imagine that my answer is deleted or downvoted - your answer will sound a little bit strange :) )

Comment: "пара" seems to be a good option: for instance, in Spanish there is a version for "чоловік"/"дружина (жінка)" - "marido"/"mujer" (marriage is implied), a gendered version of "spouse" - "esposo"/"esposa" (quite formal) and a commonly used gender-neutral "pareja" - "пара" (informal).

Comment: Perhaps, ***Обранець/Обраниця*** within some specific context? Although it's obviously not the sharp counterpart for *Spouse*, the latter being used for a husband and wife, while *Обранець/Обраниця* (like *Пара*) are used to identify not  married ones (girlfriend/boyfriend) as well.