# Чи є в українській мові відповідник до англійського слова "spouse"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, фемінітиви

> **Це запитання також має відповідь (англійською):**
>   *[Names for civil/marriage partners](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/407)*

"Spouse" - чоловік чи дружина, що знахотися у стосунках із своїм партнером. Приклад вживання:

> "There is no doubt that Russell made a mess of his relations with his
>   **spouses** and children".

[Гугл](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/spouse), [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/spouse) та [Мета](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/) пропонують варіанти "чоловік", "дружина" або "подружжя". Однак цікавить саме якийсь схожий відповідник, який би можна було застосувати як до чоловіка, так і до дружини. На Глосбі зустрів непоганий варіант "партнер у шлюбі" (ну або просто "партнер"), однак, саме це слово запозичене.

Comment: Родич-питанє: [Неодружена чи незаміжня?](/q/3121)

Comment: Все ж таки питання не зовсім є дублікатом, бо стосується перекладу, а не різниці між словами.

Comment: Тут ја позначив _родич-питанье_, а двіјника позначено осе питанье: [_Names for civil/marriage partners_](/q/407/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так вам не просто так пропонують "дружину" і "подружжя".

[Дружина](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25128&page=835):

> 2. заст., поет. **Одружений чоловік** стосовно до своєї жінки. Якби мені крила, крила Соколинії, Полетіла б я за милим, За дружиною (Т. **Шевченко**);

[Подружжя](http://sum.in.ua/s/podruzhzhja):

> 3. **Один із членів** шлюбної пари; дружина щодо свого чоловіка або чоловік щодо своєї дружини. Дядько Тимоха хоч п'ятий десяток год жив, а подружжя собі не знайшов (Борис **Грінченко**, I, 1963, 285);

Comment: Ну тоді, напевно, подружжя буде найкращим варіантом, хоч і звучить дивно  -" Як там поживає твоє подружжя?"

Comment: @Анатолій як на мене, ще дивніше вигадувати ще якесь слово, якщо історично було кілька, які вже у такому значенні використовувались.

Comment: Та я не заперечую Вашу відповідь, навпаки вважаю її дуже корисною, бо я й навіть не задумувався над тим, що у цих слів може бути таке значення. Просто ніколи їх не чув у такому контексті, того й написав, що "звучить дивно".

Comment: @Анатолій я вас неправильно зрозумів. Так, звісно, спочатку такі додаткові значення можуть здаватися вкрай дивними. Наснаги вам, ви напрочуд плідно дописуєте.